# How to get Vercel Deployment Protection working with edit mode?

Tags: vercel

According to the [Sitecore docs](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/21/sitecore-headless-development/use-vercel-s-deployment-protection-feature-with-jss-apps.html), Vercel Deployment Protection is incompatible with edit mode:

> Vercel Deployment Protection does not work with editing mode. If you require Experience Editor or Pages to function, in your site configuration, use either the default XMCloud editing host, your own editing host, or a Vercel deployment that is not deployment protected.

> If you use the Protection Bypass token to access the site in normal mode, you must use both the x-vercel-set-bypass-cookie and x-vercel-set-bypass-cookie headers (or query string parameters) to properly render all the static assets.

Why doesn't this work with edit mode? Is there no way to get edit mode working using the Protection Bypass token?